# how to map Spring controllers to their thymeleaf views(intellij14)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to configure spring boot thymeleaf and intellij, and for the most part have nailed it, but I cant seem to be able to link controllers with their views, as intellij annoyingly keeps displaying the following message, and the auto-completing the system is not working:

```
Cannot Resolve 'varName'
```

my controller looks like this "main/java/..../controller.java"

```
@Controller
public class CardsController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/card/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewCardAction(@PathVariable("id") Card card,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("card",card);
        return "cards/view";
    }
}
```

And this is my mockup view "main/resources/cards/view/cards/view":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title th:text="${card.name}"></title> <!-- this line shows the message -->
</head>
<body>
    <div th:text="${card.name}"></div> <!-- this line shows the message -->
</body>
</html>
```

is it that intelij, is still not working for this, or am I missing some configuration

NOTE: it works and compiles, just wanna enable autocomplete

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Intellij.

Here's the youtrack link:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738

It hasn't gotten much attention from the JetBrains developers yet so you may want to add your comments or vote it up there.

Comment: The jetbrains guys are working on a better spring boot support. I hope that this will lead to better support for the autoconfigured thymeleaf integration as well. It is supposed to be in a 14.x release.

Answer (score 11):

Since it is still unresolved and people might come here by search, [here is the workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738#comment=27-1110650) mentioned by zhao xinjing in the link posted in the accepted answer:

```
<!--/*--><!--@thymesVar id="loginFormBean" type="sample.system.login.LoginFormBean"--><!--*/-->
<form id="formMain" class="form-horizontal" action="#" data-th-action="@{/login}" data-th-object="${loginFormBean}" method="post"> as thymeleaf comment, nothing be left in html output
```

You can also use it to specify collections, e.g.

```
<!--/*--><!--@thymesVar id="names" type="List<String>"--><!--*/-->
<!--/*--><!--@thymesVar id="name" type="String"--><!--*/-->
<li th:each="name: ${names}" ... />
```